# how to do pandas groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

i have a excel sheet

| Animal | max Speed |
| --- | --- |
| Falcon | 34 |
| Falcon | 42 |
| Parrot | 18 |
| Parrot | 29 |

now i want to group it like this

[image]

here is my code i took it from pandas official doc but it's not working

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon','Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                   'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.]})
l = df.groupby("Animal", group_keys=True).apply(lambda x: x)
l.to_excel("kk.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: May be this: 

df=pd.read_excel("name_of_file.xlsx")  

df_grouped = df.groupby(['Animal', 'max Speed'])

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want a `group-by` operation? You don't seem to be doing any aggregation on the data based on the screenshot you've provided.

Maybe setting the index on the `Animal` column is what you need?

I.e., `df.set_index("Animal")`

Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

Comment: This just removes the default index and does not group by 'Animal' as the OP requires.

Comment: I am aware of that, but based on the screenshot he doesn't achieve anything with the group-by - there's no aggregation function.

Answer (score 0):

As @Stefan Popov points out, there is no aggregation of data so no point in groupby. Assuming that all you want is a different presentation then you could just remove the duplicated Animal names. That removes links to the data but forms the output you want.

```
l = df.duplicated('Animal', keep = 'last')
df['Animal'] = df['Animal'][l]
df['Animal']= df['Animal'].fillna('')

print(df)
```

which results in:

```
   Animal  Max Speed
0  Falcon      380.0
1              370.0
2  Parrot       24.0
3               26.0
```

which when you drop the index and send to Excel gives the result you indicated. But note that you have lost the link from some speeds to the Animal.